# Docker compose version 2.1+ on mac

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose

On the beta release of the docker app, you get docker-compose version 1.11.1, which only supports file version 2.0 (that is, the docker-compose file has 'version: "2"' at the top).

There are a few features that I would love to use from 2.1+, but it seems docker for mac is a bit behind.

Is there a way for me to use 2.1+ on a mac, or am I just going to have to wait for the 1.12 docker-compose release on mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#/download-docker-for-mac) (non beta) supports the 2.1 compose file features.

You may be confusing [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) and [Docker Engine](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/intro/) versions.

A [version 2.1 compose file](https://docs.docker.com/v1.12/compose/compose-file/#/version-21) requires a Docker Engine running 1.12.0+ and I can't find a documented Compose version requirement, but it works with Docker Compose 1.10+ here.

Compose client

```
docker-compose -v
```

Docker client

```
docker -v
```

Docker daemon/server

```
docker info | grep ^Server
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I didn't actually try setting version as 2.1. You're quite right, I was confusing docker-compose and docker engine while looking at the compatibility matrix:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/